# Where is pip.conf in my Mac which Python was installed via Homebrew?

Tags: pip

I installed Python by Homebrew, it was fine for a long time. After upgrading `pip` to the latest version, I started to get:

```
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
```

But I can not find my `pip.conf` under `/etc` or `/usr/local/etc` or `$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip` or `$HOME/.config/pip`, where can I find it?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If your `pip` version is `9.0.1`, add the following code to your `~/.pip/pip.conf` to avoid the warning.

```
[list]
format=columns
```

Comment: I didn't have a ~/.pip folder, so I created one and added a pip.conf file in it with that text in it and it magically worked. Thanks! Oh, and I had not installed Python with Homebrew. And I'm working in a virtualenv.

Comment: Thank you. As I didn't have a pip.conf anywhere I imagine it's safe to assume it doesn't exist. So I created one in the location you specified.

Comment: Use the suggested path: `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.config`

Comment: Awesome, I was looking for pip.conf all over the place but couldn't find it so I also created the file ~/.pip/pip.conf and put inside the suggest code from the warning and the error is gone. It also looks better formatted now.

Comment: @not2qubit This does not work for me in MacOS 10.12.5.

Comment: @tholu Sorry mate, can't help you as I don't use Mac. But I'd guess it also has a `find` utility, so try using it with: `find / -iname "pip.*"`.

Comment: Windows: `Users\(username)\pip\pip.ini`

Answer (score 60):

In the newer version of pip (V>10), you can directly ask your pip and it will tell you where it is looking for its configuration file(s):

```
pip config list -v
```

The above command will tell you where the pip is looking for the pip.conf file both for use and for global.

If those directories do not exist in your machine, you can simply create them and add a pip.conf inside them. Example locations on Mac:

```
$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf
$HOME/.pip/pip.conf
$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf
```

For older versions of pip (V<10), you can open a python terminal and use the pip library to extract those locations.

Comment: I think this should be the answer. It will tell you all places that pip looks for the pip.conf and then you can edit whatever one you want according to your purposes.

Answer (score 21):

`~/.pip/pip.conf` is a legacy location in macOS. Please, read the [official documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file) and put your settings into `~/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf`. It works just as must to do.

Comment: Confirmed. This path is correct and editing the pip.config works for any version of python/pip.

Answer (score 5):

To make it more clear:

For user wide:

> On macOS the configuration file is:
>   `$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf` if the directory exists else `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf`.

For virtualenv:

> On Unix and macOS the file is `$VIRTUAL_ENV/pip.conf`

[config-file(official doc)](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a `pip.conf` file in your folder of virtualenv, and write below content in the `pip.conf`

```
[list]
format=columns
```

Comment: in virtualenv case

Answer (score 1):

On macOS the configuration file is `$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf`. if you cant't find it just create.

Answer (score 1):

Check in `~` or `/Users/<your_user_name>` path. Remember to use `ls -a` to view all hidden files/directories. If `.pip/pip.conf` is not there just create it.

Answer (score 0):

You must to do the follow steps (if you are in Windows like me):

1. Acess the folder `C:\Users\`
2. If dont exists, create in `C:\Users` a new folder called "pip"
3. After, enter in folder pip created and create a new file with name "pip.ini".
4. In this file add the follow lines:

   [list]
   format=columns
5. Open the terminal (cmd, cygwin or anaconda prompt) and try again typing:

   (name_of_your_env) C:\your_path>conda env export > name_of_file.yaml
6. Acess the `C:\your_path` cited in the step 5 and notice that file exported called `name_of_file.yaml` was be created.

I hope I have helped! Bye!

Answer (score 0):

This command will work:

```
pip list --format=columns
```